# TV show with a kid called Max(?) who has a magic hat that opens portals

Tags: story-identification, magic, cartoon

I used to watch a show about a kid (Named Max maybe?) that was given this magic hat that opened portals at specific spots.

He has a fowl friend (a human who evolved into a bird or something) and a giant gladiator friend who was deathly afraid of spiders (or snakes or something).

It was a cartoon, and I can remember the plot of a few of the episodes if needed, I just can't remember the name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like [Mighty Max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Max_%28TV_series%29).

From Wikipedia: Characters include

> Max (voiced by Rob Paulsen) – The hero of the series, Max is a rambunctious young teenager who is very good at getting out of (and into) trouble. One day, he receives a mysterious package containing a videotape and a red baseball cap with a large, yellow "M" on it. The cap is actually an ancient key to various portals found throughout time and space

This matches your first character pretty perfectly.

> Virgil (voiced by the late Tony Jay) – The last living Lemurian, the next step in human evolution, as revealed in one episode. The Lemurians either created or discovered the portals, and later created the key in order to access them. Having a bird-like appearance, the Lemurians valued knowledge above all else and compiled the most extensive library the world has ever known.

Evolved, birdlike human.

> Norman (voiced by Richard Moll) – Max's bodyguard. In the time of the early Vikings, a young Norman watched his father die at the hands of Spike, an indestructible deranged and bloodthirsty warrior. Because of his size at the time, Norman couldn't help when he had the chance (he was unable to lift his father's war-axe), and thus blamed himself for the tragedy; at his father's grave, he vowed to become the greatest warrior that ever lived (cf. "Norman's Conquest"). The only creatures which give him pause for terror are spiders. In the show he meets several of tremendous size and strength.

Not quite a gladiator, but big and brawny.

Fanart of the three:

[image: Mar, Virgil, and Norma fanart]

Comment: That's totally it. Thanks! Watching it on youtube now ;P